# Hbase connectivity with Zookeeper connect and disconnect frequently but code exit with 0

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, titan

I'm using TitanDB with Storage backend Hbase manage by zookeeper and index backend : Elasticsearch
My problem is hbase connect with zookeeper and disconnect immediately but code exit with 0.

==================elasticsearch.yml=====

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch_graph_dev
script.disable_dynamic: true
node.name: "node_graph_dev"
bootstrap.mlockall: true
network.host: 127.0.0.1
```

==================hbase-site.xml========

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/zookeeper</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.manages.zk</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

==============zoo.cfg========

```
enter code here

tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

==============message on console=====

```
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x2a097d77, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure
[main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper - Process identifier=hconnection-0x2a097d77 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x154526f4c3e214d, negotiated timeout = 40000
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=catalogtracker-on-hconnection-0x2a097d77, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase-unsecure
[main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper - Process identifier=catalogtracker-on-hconnection-0x2a097d77 connecting to ZooKeeper ensemble=localhost:2181
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x154526f4c3e214e, negotiated timeout = 40000
[main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation - Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x154526f4c3e214d
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x154526f4c3e214d closed
[main-EventThread] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x154526f4c3e214e closed
[main-EventThread] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
[main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin - Started disable of titan


Titan version = 1.0.0
hbase version = 0.98.12
zookeeper version = 3.4.6
elasticsearch version = 1.5.1
```

======================================================

the above message keeps on printing many times, i just want to know is it ok that it will print many times or only once (then how to resolve it).

i can able to see index that i have created in elasticsearch gui and also table in hbase terminal + gui.

thanks

**EDIT**

HBase Log:

```
2016-04-28 14:01:41,884 INFO [pool-14-thread-1] catalog.CatalogTracker: Failed verification of hbase:meta,,1 at address=172.20.56.111,60020,1461827886746, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused 
2016-04-28 14:01:41,884 INFO [pool-14-thread-1] master.HMaster: Forcing expire of 172.20.56.111,60020,1461827886746 
2016-04-28 14:01:41,885 INFO [pool-14-thread-1] master.ServerManager: Master doesn't enable ServerShutdownHandler during initialization, delay expiring server 172.20.56.111,60020,1461827886746
```

Comment: can you look inside hbase log or zookeeper log to find why the connection close?

Comment: 2016-04-28 14:01:41,884 INFO  [pool-14-thread-1] catalog.CatalogTracker: Failed verification of hbase:meta,,1 at address=172.20.56.111,60020,1461827886746, exception=java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2016-04-28 14:01:41,884 INFO  [pool-14-thread-1] master.HMaster: Forcing expire of 172.20.56.111,60020,1461827886746
2016-04-28 14:01:41,885 INFO  [pool-14-thread-1] master.ServerManager: Master doesn't enable ServerShutdownHandler during initialization, delay expiring server 172.20.56.111,60020,1461827886746

Comment: and zookeeper? no bug?

Comment: EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1545c21bde806f9, likely client has closed socket
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
 at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:58721
INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:58721
INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58722

Comment: INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58722
INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x1545c21bde805e2 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /127.0.0.1:58721
INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x1545c21bde805e3 with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:58722

Comment: above are zookeeper logs

Comment: well this work fine at least, try stopping everything, and do `hadoop fs -rm -r /hbase/*
&& echo "rmr /hbase" | zookeeper-client`

Comment: that didn't work for me if you have any other way maybe some configuration that i missed or something else and thanks for reply.

Comment: connection refused can mean many things. do you have any firewall?

Comment: try to test your network using telnet

Comment: thanks for the reply no we don't have any firewall and telnet things not an issue with that also. I have one more thing which is about loading data into titan but i want to do it through spark so you have any idea about it and sorry for late reply

Comment: sorry no idea about that...

Comment: ok thanks for the reply

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/WkAXMbg5vYU/tt53_mRHBQAJ), those are all just `INFO` messages. It's just noise. If they bother you, you can use the log4j properties to configure the logging level to reduce them.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper=WARN
```